# Can't lookup EJB bean from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

EJB application is deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on server A and servlet is deployed to Tomcat 7 on server B. Lookup from standalone app works fine, lookup from servlet throws NameNotFoundException.
Set of libraries (from Glassfish modules directory) used in both cases is exactly the same. So we assume some additional configuration for Tomcat is required.

Relevant code from servlet deployed to Tomcat:

```
InitialContext ctx;
try {
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
   props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
   System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas.config");
   ProgrammaticLogin pl = new ProgrammaticLogin();
   pl.login("user", "s3cret".toCharArray(), "file", true);
   ctx = new InitialContext(props);
   HelloBean helloBean = (HelloBean) ctx.lookup("java:global/HelloApp/HelloBeanImpl!app.hello.HelloBean");
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Exception is always the same and there is no usefull information in getCause:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [global/HelloApp/HelloBeanImpl!app.hello.HelloBean] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [global].
   at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
   at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
   at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
   at app.servlet.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:28)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we are able to lookup secured beans from Tomcat now. You will need to put a lot of Glassfish specific jars to classpath for this to work. We have used shared loader in catalina.properties to define path to jars from Glassfish modules directory (you will probably need to exclude all servlet and jsp jars to avoid conflict with Tomcat own lib). Also make sure you don't accidentally put two security.jar to classpath. The working config looks like this:

```java
InitialContext ctx;
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty(Context.STATE_FACTORIES, "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
    props.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "./jaas.config");
    ProgrammaticLogin pl = new ProgrammaticLogin();
    boolean loginSuccessfull = pl.login("username", "password".toCharArray());
    ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    HelloBean helloBean = (HelloBean) ctx.lookup("java:global/HelloApp/HelloBeanImpl!app.hello.HelloBean");
    resp.getOutputStream().print(helloBean.sayHelloTo("user"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```